# Retrieve data from Entity and use parse JSON to read the data

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, symfony

I have a small problem, which already has become a big pain in the ***, so I have a post method usign Jquery AJAX to my entity, where a post data and then search in the entity if the there is a value. In case there is a value the value should be displayed in a text field. The fist part is done, so I can show value from the entity, but the problem is I can't figure it out how I can display only the description of the value. 
For Example:

[{"id":1,"nC":"31261","description":"05P SUBD"}]
Here is how I get my value, i would like only to display the description in the text field.

the code the Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/AjaxSearch", name="Search_HomePage")
 *
 * @return JsonResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function AjaxSearchAction(Request $request)
{
   if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {


       $name = $request->request->get('person_name');
       /** @var EntityRepository $repository */
       $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Connectors');
       $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('contacts')

           ->where('contacts.nC = :param' )
           ->setParameter('param',$name);
       $Data = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
       echo json_encode($Data);   return $this->render('MyIndex/Manufacturer_LIST.html.twig');
}
```

The HTML:

```
  <div class="response_wrapper">
    <textarea id="resposeText"></textarea>
</div>
```

and here is my java script:

```
$(document).ready(
            function ()
            {
             $('#call_back_btn' ).click(function() {
                 $.post("/app_dev.php/AjaxSearch" ,
                     {
                     person_name:$('#input_text').val()
                     } ,
                     function (data)
                     {

                         var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                            console.log(obj);
                         document.getElementById('#demo').innerHTML =
                             obj.id + "<br>" +
                             obj.nC;



                     $('#resposeText').html(obj);

                     }
                 );
             })
            }
        );
```

I have tried some examples that are answered here, but no success, So can someone please help me with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: The return data from the controller was not send properly. The right way to is :

```
return new JsonResponse(json_encode($Data));
```

and in the JS

```
 function (data)
                     {
                         console.log(data);
                          var obj =  JSON.parse(data);
                         console.log(obj);

                     $('#resposeText').val(obj[1].description);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, I think it'll help you.

```
$('#resposeText').html(obj[0].description);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but It did't do anything